# SHA1 Partial Collision

Tags: hash, sha-1

I'm working on a little python script that reads in two fairly similar English sentences (they're in text files - reading them in) and I'm trying to force a SHA1 partial collision (e.g. first 32 bits of each hash are equivalent).

Currently, my logic of thinking is as follows:

1. Concatenate empty space to the end of string 1.
2. Hash string 1.
3. Concatenate empty space to the end of string 2.
4. Hash string 2.
5. Check if `hash_of_string_01[:32]` exists in the dict, if not, move on - else exit program.
6. Check if `hash_of_string_02[:32]` exists in the dict, if not, move on - else exit program.
7. Add both new hashes to the dict.
8. Loop...

However, this isn't anywhere near efficient, nor entirely correct. I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can approach this solution...

Any guidance you can provide me would be valuable! Thank you. :)

Comment: It is necessary for you that the collisions must be constructed from the initial sentences?

Comment: Or you just need a pair of random strings that produce a partial collision?

Comment: In the latter case, then you can use some cycle detection algorithm and find a partial collision in a matter of seconds.

Comment: I have to use the initial sentences... I'll look into the cycle detection algo though tooo! Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you loose a lot of time on concatenating spaces to strings - you can use sha1().update to increment a hash state. Also [:32] in python will give you first 32 bytes, not bits (and you shouldn't convert hashes to bits of course).

Answer (score 2):

It is wanted a partial collision (over $b=32$ bits) between hashes of strings starting in distinct strings 1 and 2. I won't directly answer homework, but my hints outgrew a comment.

The solution presented should work, though details allowing to output the colliding strings are left out, and there are inefficiencies. Towards guiding optimization, I suggest estimating (perhaps, in big-$\mathcal O$ notation)

1. the expected number of steps in the algorithm,
2. the expected cumulated size of the hashed strings;
3. the expected number of insertions (and searches);
4. required memory size (which depends on the aforementioned details).

If 4 becomes outrageous, be smarter: minimize what's in the dictionarie(s), and make a second hash pass to detect the other colliding string; or store a value allowing to reconstruct that string, rather than the string itself.

You'll find that 2 suggests that (at least when $b$ grows), the naive method of obtaining the hash of a string by hashing it from the start dominates the cost of the calculation. That can be fixed in at least two ways: hashing shorter strings (hint: as suffix, combine space and some other character with similar rendering, such as non-breaking space); or if that's not allowed, being smarter at computing the hash of long strings with the same start (hint: keep appropriate hash states).

After these tweaks, if insertions and searches in the dictionaries become a serious bottleneck, or if one is tight on memory, or otherwise want to get rid of dictionaries, one can use [Floyd's cycle finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) with an appropriately defined function (hint: craft a function $f$ over $\{0,1\}^b$ such that finding a collision for $f$ solves the problem with odds about 50%). This is a great way to solve the problem, although it requires somewhat more hashes than techniques using a dictionary.

If $b$ grows to the point that the hashing needs to be distributed, see Paul C. van Oorschot and Michael J. Wiener's *Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications* ([in Journal of Cryptology](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00003816), January 1999, Volume 12, Issue 1; [free slightly earlier version](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/JoC97.pdf) available from the [first author's website](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/pubs.html)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. I def. was not looking for a concrete answer, just guidance! Thanks.

Comment: If this helped you find a solution you can still accept the answer to show that the guidance was correct.